# Excel VBA - selecting the range from first row to the last row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with VBA code. I have a sheet with a lot of data around the cells I want. I need to select data in column F, but the position of the first and last cells between the range is to be selected is changing up and down. I created the non empty cells in row X where there is no data do the LastRow function has any refernece but now I dont know how to select the first row

thx for help

Comment: Please add what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

If F1 is empty, this selects the first cell with data in the F column

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").End(xlDown).Select
```

If F1 may be non-empty you can add a check to see whether it contains text.